# Проблема при подтверждение личности в Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

Заказчик из другой страны, ему необходимо зарегистрировать приложение в Google, данные все есть. Все корректны.
Проблема в том, что не могу поменять страну, хотя при регистрации ( вроде ) нигде не указывал.
Пасспортные данные заказчика корректны.
Гугл не пропускает. Как поменять страну или какой выход есть из этой ситуации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Напиши в поддержку и опиши ситуацию, они скинут инструкцию, как исправить. Самостоятельно, уже не поменять.